# Error in code sample on MSDN?

Tags: error

I've been trying to use the method shown here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistcollection.aspx

However, I'm getting this error on line 2 below:

`Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection: type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'`

```
SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
using(SPWebCollection collWebs = oSiteCollection.AllWebs)
{
    foreach (SPWeb oWebsite in collWebs)
    {
        SPListCollection collSiteLists = oWebsite.Lists;
        foreach (SPList oList in collSiteLists)
        {
            Label1.Text += SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oWebsite.Name) + " :: " +
                SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oList.Title) + "<BR>";
        }
        oWebsite.Dispose();
    }
}
```

It won't allow SPWebCollection to be used in a using statement, because it doesn't inherit IDisposable.

Did MSDN make an error, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can surely expect errors in MSDN documentation. Right below the page, there is a Community Content area in which you can suggest them to correct the error or warn the readers of the MSDN content.

It can be corrected like:

```
SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
SPWebCollection collWebs = oSiteCollection.AllWebs

    foreach (SPWeb oWebsite in collWebs)
    {
        using(oWebsite)
        {
            SPListCollection collSiteLists = oWebsite.Lists;
            foreach (SPList oList in collSiteLists)
            {
                Label1.Text += SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oWebsite.Name) + " :: " +
                    SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oList.Title) + "<BR>";
            }
        }
    }
```